# GST Issue For australia store

Tags: magento, gstreamer

My client has a special requirement that is gst should be show on front end as well as on admin but this gst should not be added on grand total.how i can done this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're double posting, this has already been answered on the Magento Forum:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/278928/#t385908